# SSH X11 in Android?

Tags: android, ssh, x11

Is there any way to redirect X11 apps to android. I mean, like when you do `ssh -X` to some host.

There are android apps for ssh, but they don't seem to have an option for X11 forwarding.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This does not appear to be a programming question. Try https://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: VNC apps exist... I'm not sure how X11 would be any different (or more useful)

Comment: @cricket_007 it could be faster since you can only use 1 program, not the whole desktop

Comment: @CommonsWare a friend of mine told me solving this might need extensive scripting and coding

Comment: "might need extensive scripting and coding" == too broad and off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: Besides, you seem to not to have researched your options... https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-device-as-x11-server-for-a-remote-machine-over

Comment: A maintained and updated version of the darkside xserver mentioned by datenwolf can be found here: https://github.com/nwrkbiz/android-xserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an X11 server for Android (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer&hl=en). With an X server running you can use regular forwarding via SSH.